# How to make discord python bot react to its own message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Currently working on a small bot which sends an embed and I want it to react to itself but am unsure on how to do that. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

Get the message you want to react to and use [Client.add_reaction()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_reaction)

For example, if you're reacting to an embed

```
msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel,embed=embed)
await bot.add_reaction(msg, "")
```

Comment: I get an error saying ctx is not defined, where do I implement that?

Comment: `ctx` is a context variable that you can pass to your function to grab certain attributes of the message. For example: `async def test(ctx):`.It would help if you would share the code of the function where you create the embed

Comment: This is the part of the code where the embed is created:

@client.command()
async def embed1():
    
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Title",
        color=0xa27250)
    
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="")
    embed.add_field(name="text", value="text", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="text")

    await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='channel id'), embed=embed)

Comment: Yeah, so now at the last line there do `msg = await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='458269214822891522'), embed=embed)` and then `await bot.add_reaction(msg, "")` or whichever emote you want just like in the example above

Comment: That works and all, but when i execute the function I get: "Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)" I looked it up but the embed isn't even close to the 2000 char limit?

Comment: It might happen because in `embed.add_field(name="SOMETHING", value="SOMETHING", inline=False)` the fields `name` and `value` cannot be empty

Comment: Those are not empty

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in your code

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

Your bot will not respond to itself, and it shouldn't respond to itself normally.  A way around this would be to put any code you want to execute despite `message.author == client.user` above it.  For instance:

```
# This will respond to itself
if (message.content.lower() == "!yell"):
    msg = "!yell"
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

# This checks to see if the author is the client    
if message.author == client.user:
    return

# This will not respond to itself
if (message.content.lower() == "!yell2"):
    msg = "!yell"
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

!yell will result in your bot talking to itself until it reaches the message threshold, however, !yell2 will not because it come after the section that checks whether or not it's the client.user.