# Getting bot to react to it's own message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How would I make the bot react to it's own message? I know it's probably a simple enough thing but I can't find an answer. Thanks in advance.

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Basic ping command",
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send("Pong.");
        message.react("");
    },
};
```

Edit: I forgot to say in here that this is Discord.JS, not python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea but you add the reaction to the wrong message. To react to the message the bot has send, you can use the Promise returned by [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send). Take a look at the example code below and give it a try:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Basic ping command",
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send("Pong.").then((botMessage) => {
            botMessage.react("");
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173483/how-to-make-discord-python-bot-react-to-its-own-message) article

the code should be

```
bot.add_reaction(msg, "")
```